# Hyperledger validating peer fails to restart

Tags: hyperledger

I have a Hyperledger setup consisting of one membership service and one validating peer.

I am able to run the membership service and validating peer using the following commands.

Membership Service:

```
docker run   --name c_membersrvc   --net mynet   --ip 172.17.0.50   --rm -it -e MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true   hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc   membersrvc
```

Validating Peer:

```
docker run   --name c_vp0   --net mynet --ip 172.17.0.100 -p 172.17.0.1:7050:7050 -p 172.17.0.1:7053:7053   --rm -it   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock   -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0   -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true   -e CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=noop   -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true   -e CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=true   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT   hyperledger/fabric-peer   peer node start
```

However, when I stop the validating peer and restart it using the same command as indicated above, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.
```

I am able to restart the validating peer successfully if I restart the membership service first.  In an actual deployment, I don't think my approach of restarting the membership service every time a validating peer needs to restart is practical.

Is there another way to successfully restart a validating peer without the need to restart the membership service?

I saw a similar post on the error  **Identity or token does not match**  but this is due to a user/client logging-in through a validating peer.  The proposed solution is to use the Node.js SDK to register/enroll clients.  I am not sure if the same solution is applicable for the validating peer restart issue.

Answer (score 1):

When VP is started for the first time it:

1. Reads enrollID and enrollSecret from core.yaml
2. Sends these credentials to the Membership service and receives Enrolment certificate as a response.
3. Saves enrolment certificate in /var/hyperledger/prodution/... folder

When you try to restart VP, docker creates new container with empty `/var/hyperledger/prodution/...` folder. VP tries to generate new Enrloment certificate using the same credentials, but Membership service will decline this request with `Identity or token does not match.` error message. That happens because just one Enrolment certificate per account can be generated.

In case when membership service is restarted  - it starts from scratch and has no information about previous enrolments, as a result next enrolment request will be accepted.

As an option, you can save certificate outside of container. Just map any folder from your host system to `/var/hyperledger/prodution/...` in container.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey.  I'll try this approach.

Comment: Hi @Sergey.  I tried it but is encountering an error: ` Error opening DB: IO error`.  I'll post another question to describe the details.